# $\mathbb{R}$- Topology Open Set Question

Tags: general-topology

If $A\times \{x_{0}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ open

will the $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open ?

Comment: In the usual topology $A\times\{x_0\}$ will be open only when $A=\emptyset$. Therefore $A$ will be open, yes.

Comment: thank you user647486